# Shiny loop not breaking

Tags: r, api, shiny, nested-loops

I am trying to obtain data using the gbif API through the R package rgbif. To make sure I'm getting observations for each month of the year I have created a nested loop for the years of interest and the months. The user selects the years and then presses the action button to start the loop, however the loop is not breaking. I have added a tryCatch for the selection to stop the loop breaking when an month returns no observations, however the loop is not breaking at all and I can't see why. A reproducible example is below.

```
library(rgbif)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("In1", "Input 1", 2008),
  numericInput("In2","Input 2",2008),
  actionButton("go","Get Data"),
  
  mainPanel(tableOutput("data"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
  data1 <- eventReactive(input$go,{
    
    start <-input$In1
    
    end<-input$In2
    
    data1 <- data.frame()
    
    for (j in start:end) {
      local({        
        for (i in 1:12) {
          skip_to_next<-FALSE
          
          gbif<-occ_data(limit=10, decimalLatitude ="49.67,55.92",
                         decimalLongitude ="-6.7,2.09",month=i,year=j)
          
          gbif_data<-gbif$data
          
          gbif_data<-tryCatch(select(gbif_data,c(name,decimalLatitude,decimalLongitude,eventDate,class,
                                                   vernacularName)),
                              error=function(e){skip_to_next<<-TRUE})
          
          if(skip_to_next){next}
          
          data1<-rbind(data1,gbif_data)
          }
      })
    }
    return(data1)
  })
  
  output$data <- renderTable({data1()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

I have tried moving the local({}) part to inside both loops.